# Trigonometry $1+\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos{x}}$

Tags: trigonometry

How does one get the following equalities ?

$1+\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos{x}}=\sqrt{2}\frac{\cos{(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)}}{\cos{x}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1+\tan x=1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}}{\frac1{\sqrt2}}=\frac{\cos x\sin \frac {\pi}{4}+\sin x\cos \frac {\pi}{4}}{\cos \frac{\pi}{4}\cos x}=\frac{\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\cos \frac{\pi}{4}\cos x}$$
Using the fact that $\cos \frac {\pi}{4}=\sin \frac {\pi}{4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Thank you very much ! And what about the last part ?

Comment: The last one follows from the fact that $\cos \frac {\pi}{4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\sin\left(\frac {\pi}{2}-x\right)=\cos x$